# Checkout top link resulting in 500 error

Tags: toplinks

I'm in need of some assistance.  When I click on the top link "Checkout" on my site, redirected to https://MyURL.com/checkout/ and given a 500 error. When I clink on "Cart" and then "Proceed to Checkout" I reach to https://MYURL.com/checkout/onepage and the working checkout page.Using Chrome Inspect on the "Checkout" top link I get:

```
<a href="https://MYURL.com/checkout/" title="Checkout" class="top-link-checkout">Checkout</a>
```

It would seem the quick fix would be to add "onepage" to the end of that href?  Problem is, I can't seem to find that code anywhere to edit it, or anyth on the backend of Magento where one redirects top links if there is such a thing.

I'm starting to lose my sanity over what seems like a quick fix.  Please advise.  Be gentle.  I'm fairly new to all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable template path hints for get file location for this follow the following steps:

1. Go to Magento admin panel->systems->configuration
2. Choose your store view on top left corner in Current Configuration Scope
3. Go to Advanced tab. Under that click on Developer->Debug. Click yes on Template path hints.
4. Refresh your frontend

Now you can see the path of files. When you get the file location just replace the anchor value.You can get checkout url :

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl(); ?>">Checkout</a>
```

Comment: I did enable the template path hints as you suggested.  Unfortunately, all the red path hints from the top links are stacked on top of one another making it impossible to find the one specific for Checkout.  Are there any other methods of finding the path that you know of?  I'll keep looking for the href tag, and I thank you for your help.